Calculate field unavailable
We are trying to calculate fields in the attribute table of a feature layer, but the "Calculate" button is greyed out, as well as the option when right-clicking in the header. It is happening in more than one layer, in more than one project.
We have ensured that there are no joins, we've tried exporting the table, and we have ensured the field is numeric. Editing appears to be turned on.




I'm going off of memory from years back and much of that was ArcMap but we found that if we had layers in a geodatabase there could be locking issues, especially if they were in a feature dataset with topology rules.  You could use your regular file explorer to see if there are lock files in the folder.

Please always provide error messages as formatted text rather than only in pictures.

Rather than using the UI try running the calculate field tool from toolbox and if that errors it may give you a hint to the underlying issue?
